# Why am I getting an UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to write a file to LocalStorage in Azure

Tags: azure, local-storage

I have created a local storage in my web role called "MyTestCache" as so in my 
ServiceDefinition.csdef file. But when ever I call the System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes method I get a UnauthorizedAccess exception. Does anyone know what would be causing this? I dont get this when creating the directory in the code below, only when writing. I am using SDK 1.3.

```
 private void SaveFileToLocalStorage(byte[] remoteFile, string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            LocalResource myIO = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MyTestCache");

            // Creates directory if it doesn't exist (ie the first time)
            if (!Directory.Exists(myIO.RootPath + "/thumbnails"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(myIO.RootPath + "/thumbnails");
            }

            string PathToFile = Path.Combine(myIO.RootPath + "/thumbnails", filePath);
            var path = filePath.Split(Char.Parse("/"));

            // Creates the directory for the content item (GUID)            
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(myIO.RootPath + "/thumbnails", path[0])))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(myIO.RootPath + "/thumbnails", path[0]));
            }

            // Writes the file to local storage.
            File.WriteAllBytes(PathToFile, remoteFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do some exception handling
            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just as an aside, you can call `Path.Combine` with multiple params - so `Path.Combine(myIO.RootPath, "thumbnails", path[0])` - and you can get the directory of a file path using `Path.GetDirectoryName()`

Answer (score 2):

Check ACLs. In SDK 1.3 by default web roles are started in full IIS worker process, using Network Service as identity of application pool. Make sure Network Service account has permissions to execute operations you expect. In your case you are trying to create a sub-directory, so most probably you need at least Write permission. If your role also modifies ACLs on this directory, you need to grant Full access to this directory.

Comment: seva is right in sdk 1.3 by default web roles are started in full IIS worker process .Check ur permissions.You need to grant full access for the directory.